# Server IP Change Screen not shown in Android Nexus 7

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst

I have used Mobilfirst 6.3 and using connectonstarup feature.

1. When the application can't connect to the server
2. The dialog box appears with 3 buttons
3. There we click details to modify the settings of the Server IP

It works fine in all the tabs and mobile except the Google Nexus 7(Android 5.0). After i click the details screen the application stucks and i can't do anything.

Comment: Will be tested, however note that using connectOnStartup in initOption.js is deprecated - do not use it.

Comment: sure ill make the changes.

Answer (score 0):

The below was tested using `WL.Client.connect()`, because `connectOnStartup` is deprecated (no longer maintained and tested) and should no longer be used.

I cannot confirm this.

I've created the same scenario using a Nexus 7 (running Android OS 5.0.2).
After the application failed to connect to the MFP Server, I tapped on the Details button.

In the App Diagnostics screen you can do two things:

1. Reload in order to try to connect again
2. Copy the details that you see in the table

Tapping on the Reload button indeed reloads the app (and again shows me the dialog to either close the dialog, reload the app or view the app diagnostics table.

Copying the details copies the details and you can then paste them in an email screen or some other text editing window.

Both actions work for me.

Comment: I wasn't able to reach the App Diagnostics screen at all.

Comment: my application remains still after the dialog box closes and i didn't get any error log or anything.

Comment: Correction: I got to it by using WL.Client.connect(), since connectOnStartup is deprecated (no longer maintained and tested) and should no longer be used.